# change timezone for crontab

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron

my machine is running on PKT and so my crons are also working according to it.

```
* * * * * date >> /tmp/cronResult
```

it gives me time according to my local machine time.
I want these crons to run acording to GMT.

how is that possible.
I have tried to put

```
export TZ=GMT
```

in `/etc/default/cron`
but that doesn't work.

Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: Why can't you just adjust the time in the crontab to account for the local offset from UTC (note GMT doesn't really exist anymore)? PKT is UTC+0500 so if you want something to run at midday UTC schedule it in crontab for 1700.

Comment: i also want it to take care of time saving which can make cron to run one hour earlier or an hour later. i want to know if i can handle it for generic cases.